# Reference equality for java.lang.String in Scala

Tags: string, scala, reference, equality, referenceequals

One would expect that even though strings are immutable, value-equality and reference-equality would not be the same for java.lang.String objects in Scala. This means that two string-holding `val`s should not be reference-equal even when their strings are identical. But here's what I get in a 2.9.1.final REPL:

```
scala> val s1 = "a"; val s2 = "a"
s1: java.lang.String = a
s2: java.lang.String = a

scala> s1 eq s2
res0: Boolean = true
```

Any idea why the result was not `false`? The same experiment with `List("a")` instead of `"a"` works as expected. The `eq` method is marked as final in [AnyRef](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/AnyRef.html). Is there any compiler magic done specifically for `String` or `java.lang.String`?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes it's compiler magic. Specifically, it's called *interning*. Java does it as well, and it's simply for efficiency reasons, such as memory usage and allowing comparisons without comparing every character. Here's a [Wikipedia article on it](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/String_interning). You can also intern Strings manually with the `intern()` method.

Answer (score 4):

From the [Java language specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5):

> A string literal is a reference to an instance of class `String` (§4.3.1, §4.3.3).
>
> Moreover, **a string literal always refers to the same instance of class `String`**. This is because string literals - or, more generally, strings that are the values of constant expressions (§15.28) - are "interned" so as to share unique instances, using the method `String.intern`.

Comment: Thanks! Interestingly, when I change my example to start with `val s1 = "aa"; val s2 = "a" + "a"`, the result is still the same, even though `"a" + "a"` is not a constant expression (is it?). So it looks like Scala does a bit more than what the Java spec says.

Comment: `"a" + "a"` **is** a constant expression, see [Constant Expressions](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.28)

Comment: The Java spec for constant expressions doesn't seem to be exactly the same for Scala. For instance, using one of the examples given on that Constant Expressions page, `"The integer " + java.lang.Long.MAX_VALUE + " is mighty big."` is not interned by scalac.